# How to duplicate Google Maps' - click to call GOOGLE HANGOUTS phone link

Tags: html, google-maps, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

In the latest google maps update there are hyperlinks on phone numbers that initiates a google hangouts (click to call) function.

An example can be [seen here](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=fedex%20cookeville&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=fedex%20cookeville&tbs=lf:1,lf_ui:4&rflfq=1&rlha=0&rllag=36165939,-85495506,5716&tbm=lcl&rlfi=hd:;si:11275565748689068254) if you're logged in and hover over the hyperlinked phone number you'll see it says, "Call Via Hangouts".

This is not the same as the Google Hangouts API which creates a button like this:  [image]

Using this source

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<g:hangout render="createhangout" invites="[{ id : '+1800FREE411', invite_type : 'PHONE' }]"></g:hangout>
```

Basically I want the same as the google maps links... an html link that initiates the call without the button image.

Any easy way to get rid of the button and make the link the phone number?